# How do you change htaccess to convert domain.com to www.domain.com without changing sub.domain.com?

Tags: .htaccess

What should your .htaccess look like to redirect domain.com to www.domain.com but to leave sub.domain.com unchanged?

Here

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

converts domain.com to www.domain.com but also converts sub.domain.com to www.domain.com/subdomains/sub(where it's contents are). I want sub.domain.com to remain in the browser window while the contents of www.domain.com/subdomains/sub are shown(as usual).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rule is running for every domain that is not `www.domain.com` Instead you want to run when the HTTP_HOST is `domain.com' which you can do like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

In regular expressions, `^` denotes the start of the string and `$` denotes the end of the string and `!` at the beginning means match everything that is not the following. That's going to catch all domains that are not exactly www.domain.com. In my example, I am only matching domains that are exactly `domain.com` and redirecting it to `www.domain.com`

I normally do that in my vhost file though.

```
<VirtualHost myip:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    Redirect permanent / http://www.domain.com/
    CustomLog logs/domain.com/access_log combined
    ErrorLog logs/domin.com/error_log
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost myid:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com
    ServerName www.domain.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
    CustomLog logs/domain.com/access_log combined
    ErrorLog logs/domain.com/error_log

    <Directory "/var/www/domain.com">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What is a virtual host. I replaced my htaccess with it while changing the domain-name to mine and I got an Internal Server Error.

Comment: virtual hosts are a different way of configuring your web server. They are in the apache conf, not htaccess. If I were you, I'd just implement my htaccess example for simplicity.